# Extracting pixels from a raster based on defined zones in another raster - ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, zonal-statistics, extract

This seems like it should be a very simple task but for some reason is more difficult than I thought.

Basically I have rasters with water table depth information, with each pixel representing a depth in meters.

I have a global land-use raster, with each pixel representing a number from 1-6 (different land-use types).

I basically want to know what is the water depth in each of these 6 land-use types. Zonal statistics gives me pretty much all the information I need, EXCEPT the quartiles. And Extract by mask doesn't summarize the data by zone.

I want to know the mean, median, quartiles, and standard deviation of water table depth within each zone (land-use type).

What should I be doing?

Comment: Did you check the answer of this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202446/calculating-first-quartile-of-a-raster-by-zonal-statistics?

Comment: Reclassify depth into say 200 values, use tabulate area and do the rest in Excel.